# equal expression doesn't work as expected in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

My first expression

```
 alert($('.dateTimeHolder').html()); //returned Date - Time *
```

My second

```
 alert($('.dateTimeHolder').html()  == 'Date - Time *'); return false
```

Why the second expression is false?

Answer (score 0):

Once possibility is the leading and trailing spaces so try to use trim() to remove them

```
alert($('.dateTimeHolder').html().trim() == 'Date - Time *');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to trim the `html` you are comparing to a static string, there could be some leading/trailing spaces/newline chars.

```
alert($.trim($('.dateTimeHolder').html())  == 'Date - Time *'); // return false
```

```js
alert($.trim($('.datetime').html()) === "date - time*");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='datetime'>
date - time*
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this [trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)

```
 alert($('.dateTimeHolder').html().trim()  == 'Date - Time *'); return false
```

Comment: You trim link leading to `jQuery.trim()` not to `.trim()` docs.